# Ensuring sensitive code is run only server-side with NextJS, where can such code be ran from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm learning NextJS and I'm trying to determine how to layout my project with a clean architecture that's also secure. However, I'm not sure about where to store code that contains potentially sensitive data (ie. connections to databases, accessing the file system, etc.). I've read the docs, but I'm still unsure about this one issue.

In my project layout, I have 2 directories that that relate to this problem: a top level `/lib` I added and the `/pages/api` directory that comes baked into every NextJS project.

To my understanding `/pages/api` NEVER sees the client-side and is hence safe for sensitive code. It should only be used as somewhere to do post, patch, delete, etc. operations. An example of where `/pages/api` is used would be when you make a post request to the server from a form. You can call an api from this route from ANYWHERE, for example: a form component, the `/lib` folder, a page in `/pages`, an external 3rd party api - wherever.

On the other hand, the top level `/lib` directory, is a place for boilerplate code, carrying out tedious operations such as sorting blog posts into alphabetical order, doing math computations, etc. that's not necessarily "secret" or sensitive - just long and annoying code. The `/lib` directory will ALWAYS be seen by the client-side - *even if it's code that's only called by a server-side method such as `getStaticProps()`*.

In short, anything remotely sensitive should always be made as a post, patch, put etc. request to the `/pages/api` directory, and any long/tedious code that's not sensitive should be refactored to the `/lib` directory.

Do I have this all right?

Comment: Great question, wish more people pitched architectural review on here.

Comment: _"The `/lib` directory will ALWAYS be seen by the client-side - even if it's code that's only called by a server-side method"_ - that's not accurate. As long as you use the code in `/lib` on the server-side only (API routes, `getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths` or `getServerSideProps`) that code will never be exposed to the client, as it will not be bundled in the client bundle.

Comment: To be clear: **`lib` is not an important directory to NextJS**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do you sensitive stuff in api routes, `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`. None of your code in `/lib` will be seen by the client unless your page actually imports code from there.

Since you were talking about db connections, it's very unlikely you'd be able to connect to your db from the browser by accident. Almost none of the libraries used to connect to db won't work from the browser and you also can only access env variables that start with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` on the client.

You also need to keep in mind that every file under `/api` will be an api route, so you should put your helper files inside `/lib` instead of `/api`. If you put them under the `/api` that could lead to security vulnerabilities  since anyone can trigger the default exported function of the files under `/api`.

If you for some reason need to be absolutely certain that some code isn't bundled to the files that clients will load even if you by accidentally to import it, it can be done with custom webpack config. Note that I'd only look into this option if the code in itself is very sensitive. As in that someone being able to read the code would lead to consequences. Not talking about code doing db queries or anything like that, even if you imported them by accident to client bundles, it wouldn't pose any threat as the client cannot connect to your database.

Comment: "None of your code in /lib will be seen by the client unless your page actually imports code from there"

So if I do something like `import { getAllPostIds, getPostData } from '../../lib/posts';` from one of my pages in `/pages`, where the two functions I import (getAllPostIds, getPostData) are sensitive, is that safe?

Comment: What is the threat here? Is your code really sensitive? A code doing db queries isn't "sensitive" in a sense that it doen't matter if someone sees it, it wouldn't work on the client anyway. But in theory yes it should work like you said. If the code really is sensitive, I would still move the sensitive code to a different file instead of trusting tree shaking to do its job. It's a feature to minimize bundle sizes after all, not a security feature.

Comment: I'm not doing this from an example, just preparing for development so I know how to set things up. That makes sense though! So `/api` is a safe spot, and `/lib` is for helping, but not necessarily guaranteed to be secure, gotcha.

Comment: Well keep in mind that every file under `/api` is an api route, so you should put your helper files inside `/lib` instead of `/api`. If you put them under the `/api` that could lead to security vulnerabilities and some unexpected consequences since anyone can trigger the default export function of the files under `/api`.

Comment: > "None of your code in /lib will be seen by the client unless your page actually imports code from there. ... Almost none of the libraries used to connect to db won't work from the browser"


@FINDarkside So if I have a function in `/lib` that takes a parameter and uses it to update the DB and import that function in a page (but outside of getServerSideProps), a user would or would not be able to discover and successfully call that function?

Can you expand on why these functions wouldn't work on the client?

Comment: The code would be bundled with your code, but there's probably nothing sensitive there. User won't be able to run the code because there's no db connection from the client side. Also I doubt any db connector lib would even work on browser env so your project would almost certainly not build. So it doesn't make sense to do what you're trying to do, it wouldn't work. You need to do db stuff in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

The `/pages/api` and `lib` should be safe enough. These files are not exposed by Next.js.
Next.js exposes the files in your `public` folder.
What you have said about the `lib` is correct. It is just a folder that can be used to house helper functions that you can reuse within your code.

`getStaticProps` only runs on the server-side. It will never run on the client-side. It won’t even be included in the JS bundle for the browser. That means you can write code such as direct database queries without them being sent to browser.
You can safely make your calls with this function.

There is a tool you can use to validate that code in getStaticProps only runs serverside and never gets exposed client side.
Link to tool: https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/

Comment: So I can write sensitive stuff in `/lib` without any worry, even if I import what the sensitive functions return to a more exposed place, such as `/pages`?

Answer (score 1):

I've used `/lib` in much the same way you intend on a number of Next projects and haven't had any problems. As others have mentioned, if you are server-side generating everything with `getStaticProps`, you should be fine.

One thing I've run into is client and server side getting out of sync between the actual client and server (especially with iFrame or data that gets manipulated after a fetch). That doesn't cause security issues but it is something to think through architecturally. Next exposes its router if you need to sync effects to URL changes.